# Задержка CURL в PHP

Tags: curl, php

Есть примерно такой код:

```
$this->post('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zIaxHPa..'); // curl

// другой код
```

Вопрос, как программно сделать чтобы пользователь якобы пробыл на странице https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zIaxHPa.. 10-15 секунд?

Или как-то так, чтобы `// другой код` выполнился через 10 секунд например, а эти 10 секунд просматривалась страница.

Comment:     sleep()

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sleep.php

Comment: и как это поможет?

Comment: я, конечно, знаю один метод, который должен работать из коробки, но я никогда не буду помогать накручивать счетчики.

Comment: @Etki поможет если напрячься и подумать, чего не сделал ты написав этот комментарий.

Comment: @Bastian, человеку нужно симулировать присутствие на странице. PHP без дополнительной громадной работы не сможет сделать ничего, кроме как отправить запрос, который будет воспринят, как новое посещение страницы, что никак не поможет.

Comment: @Bastian, sleep никак не помогает, к сожалению. Он как setTimeout в JS, только замедляет выполнение всего.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько мне известно, время нахождения пользователя на странице отслеживает javascript метрика. Симуляция посещения пользователем страницы средствами PHP в данном случае невозможна.

**Обновление**

По сути - да, можно посмотреть в JS, как работает метрика, и  симулировать ее поведение в php, но, по-моему, это можно считать извращением. :) Полноценно симулировать поведение пользователя можно через JS в консоли браузера. Это и проще, и более эффективно с точки зрения результата (сервер будет считать, что работает реальный пользователь, метрика полностью отработает), но гораздо более затратно с точки зрения расходования ресурсов.

Comment: @undestroyer по сути, нет ничего невозможного )